# ERROR running force:data:tree:import: The requested resource does not exist when using force:data:tree:import

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, data, import, sobject-tree

I'm having some trouble with importing Json file which containing data in SObject using

```
sfdx force:data:tree:import -p ./data/Project__c-Round__c-plan.json
```

It spits out an error which is:

> ERROR running force:data:tree:import:  The requested resource does not
> exist

I have double checked the path and also existence of the json itself in folder data.

this is the Project__c-Round__c-plan.json

```
    [
        {
            "sobject": "Project__c",
            "saveRefs": true,
            "resolveRefs": false,
            "files": [
                "Project__cs.json"
            ]
        },
        {
            "sobject": "Round__c",
            "saveRefs": false,
            "resolveRefs": true,
            "files": [
                "Round__cs.json"
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Comment: did you get any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

**Root Cause**: In my case, When I created data JSON file, My dev Hub was not configured with any namespace but after namespace configuration, I got this issue.

**Solution**: Change data JSON files and add your namespace with every file and fields.

**Old Name**:  FileName.json and fields in the file was fieldName

**New Name**: **NameSpace__** FileName.json, **NameSpace__** fieldName

Before: (File Name: ABC.json)

```
{
"records": [
    {
        "attributes": {
            "type": "ABC__c",
            "referenceId": "ABC__cRef1"
        },
        "Name": "Main ABC",
        "IsActive__c": true,
        "Label__c": "Main Process",
        "MNO__c": "@MNO__cRef1",
        "Order__c": 1
    }
]
```

}

After: (File Name: NAMESPACE__ABC.json)

```
{
"records": [
    {
        "attributes": {
            "type": "NAMESPACE__ABC__c",
            "referenceId": "NAMESPACE__ABC__cRef1"
        },
        "Name": "Main ABC",
        "NAMESPACE__IsActive__c": true,
        "NAMESPACE__Label__c": "Main Process",
        "NAMESPACE__MNO__c": "@NAMESPACE__MNO__cRef1",
        "NAMESPACE__Order__c": 1
    }
]
```

}

==========================================

I also got the same issue. I have reinstalled the latest version but did not get luck. When I used --json then I got the following error message.

```
{
"status": 1,
"name": "NOT_FOUND",
"message": "The requested resource does not exist",
"exitCode": 1,
"commandName": "DataTreeImportCommand",
"stack": "NOT_FOUND: The requested resource does not exist\n    
at HttpApi.getError (/usr/local/lib/sfdx/node_modules/jsforce/lib/http-api.js:250:13)\n    
at /usr/local/lib/sfdx/node_modules/jsforce/lib/http-api.js:95:22\n    
at tryCallOne (/usr/local/lib/sfdx/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)\n    
at /usr/local/lib/sfdx/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:123:15\n    
at flush (/usr/local/lib/sfdx/node_modules/asap/raw.js:50:29)\n    
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)\nOuter stack:\n    
at Function.wrap (/usr/local/lib/sfdx/node_modules/@salesforce/core/lib/sfdxError.js:151:27)\n    
at DataTreeImportCommand.catch (/usr/local/lib/sfdx/node_modules/salesforce-alm/dist/ToolbeltCommand.js:216:46)\n    
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)",

"warnings": [] }
```